# How to find arguments to an application on macOS X?

Tags: macos, applications, command-line

I am looking for a way of finding out undocumented command arguments to a application on macOS.

For example, I can run something like this:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  --remote-debugging-port=xxxx
```

Where `--remote-debugging-port` is a command-line argument to the Chrome app. I would like to know more undocumented arguments for such apps, say `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`.

PS: My question is something similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869219/how-can-i-find-out-if-an-exe-has-command-line-options - which is for Windows.

Comment: A DMG is just a disk image, it doesn't have command arguments :-)

Comment: @nohillside - Thank you for the edit, much appriciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

Argument handling is part of the application code so there is no easy way to find these options from the outside. Besides searching on the Internet you can run

```
strings ANY-BINARY | grep '^--'
```

to search for them within an application. If you do so you will need to look both in `.../MacOS/*` and in any frameworks included in `.../Frameworks`.